# Using hidden input variable in the base class to persist value across postbacks

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

In my base class:

```
public abstract class BaseUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
  protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden MyID;

  //This is called when the page loads
  private void OnLoad()
  {
     MyID.Value = "testId";
  }

 protected void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = this.MyID.Value;
}

}
```

In my user control that inherits from BaseUsercontrol The ascx has:

```
<asp:Button id="btnTest" runat="server" OnClick="OnButtonClick" />
```

Why can't I use the hidden input variable this way??

Comment: What exactly is happening when you try to use it that way?  Do you get an error?  Does nothing happen?

Comment: MyID has a null reference after a few postbacks

Comment: Are you just trying to persist values during postbacks? Why not use viewstate?

Comment: With hidden input variables, I can access the value from JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having an HiddenInputField in your .ascx with id= MyID and that's what you are trying to use then that is not how you do it.

You will need to do a FindControl.

Or
You might want to provide more details about why and what exactly you want to achieve.
Because there might be other possible ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: The HiddenInputField is in the base user control and not in the ascx markup. It's declared as protected and used within the same base user control class.

Comment: The are you dynamically adding this to your control or what is the purpose using it? May be I am not getting a clear picture.